# Wildfly 18 log strategy doesn't respect max-backup-index and keeps all server.log files

Tags: logging, wildfly, wildfly-18

We have a WildFly 18 with the following logging strategy:

```
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:10.0">
    ...
    <profile>
        ...
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:8.0">
            ...
            <periodic-size-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <rotate-size value="100M"/>
                <max-backup-index value="10"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-size-rotating-file-handler>
```

Even though we specify a `periodic-size-rotating-file-handler` with a `max-backup-index`, all `server.log` files are kept and never removed:

[image: endless list of server.log files]

What are we doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `max-backup-index` is only used for files not rotated by the date. See https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/18.0/subsystem/logging/periodic-size-rotating-file-handler/index.html. There is an old [issue](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/LOGMGR-57) which asks for this ability, but it requires assumptions to be made about file names.

Comment: Oh my, didn't notice they said "Any backups rotated by the suffix will not be purged during a size rotation". Thanks anyway :-/